# iphone,how to create NSOperationQueue

Tags: iphone

I've got a couple background tasks to process while still keeping the UI responsive. I started down the path of creating and managing threads, but soon came across the NSOperations. Sounds like a better solution . . .

However, I cannot seem to get a reference to the NSOperationQueue. The Threading Programming Guide suggests the following

```
@implementation MyCustomClass
- (void)launchTaskWithData:(id)data
{

    NSInvocationOperation* theOp = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                    selector:@selector(myTaskMethod:) object:data];

    // Add the operation to the internal operation queue managed by the application delegate.
    [[MyAppDelegate sharedOperationQueue] addOperation:theOp];
}

// This is the method that does the actual work of the task.
- (void)myTaskMethod:(id)data
{
    // Perform the task.
}
```

. . . but I (and more importantly, the compiler) don't see the 'sharedOperationQueue' message when I implement the code in my app.

What am I missing?? Is sharedOperationQueue deprecated and no longer available? How can I get an NSOperationQueue reference?

Answer (score 2):

`sharedOperationQueue` is not part of the official API. It is a custom method you are supposed to implement yourself, in this example as a class method in your app delegate class. The method should create and return `NSOperationQueue` or, if it already has created the queue, simply return the existing one.

How you implement this in your case is up to you. You don't have to follow the example. Simple create an operation queue with `alloc`/`init` (no magic here) and store a reference to it in a property so that you can later release it when you no longer need it.

Answer (score 1):

Cocoa Is My Girlfriend has a [good tutorial](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/16/cocoa-tutorial-nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue/), this will help you to use NSOperationQueue.

Answer (score -1):

You have to declare application delegate before adding operation:

```
AppDelegateClass * MyAppDelegate = [NSApp delegate];
```